# Buildozer APK crash "Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x9"

Tags: kivy, apk, buildozer

I've build my first apk using buildozer without error, but now it crash on android.
I found in logs "Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9" but I don't know why I get this error:
Here [are the logs](https://pastebin.com/TriqjJbd)`logs` and here [is buildozer.spec](https://pastebin.com/Z88T9qer)`spec`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post the full logcat output

Comment: Logs in my original message are logcat output

Comment: Not sure what is causing it, but the actual error is `couldn't find "libpython3.7m.so"`. It also couldn't find '3.6' or '3.5'.

Comment: Thanks, I did not see him. I opened an issue at https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1133

Answer (score 0):

I had the error you mentioned, but it turned out I had a different problem. That "Consumer closed..." message is just a signal that something else is wrong.

Now, as John Anderson already stated, the actual problem you have is that Python never loads when your app starts. On GitHub, you said that you have Python 3.7 installed, so not sure why, it doesn't load in your case.

**I have the same errors, but have Python 3.8 installed, so it loads and everything works as expected.**